# How to use docker-compose to build an application on a CI?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I  would like to configure a CI such as TravisCI to build my application from Docker. My application has two part: Javascript and Python.

I thought to use `docker-compose` to do this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  node:
    image: node:12.8.0-buster
    volumes:
    - .:/srv
  python:
    image: python:3.7.4-buster
    volumes:
    - .:/src
```

I would like to have a Makefile such as:

```
all: foo bar

foo:
    docker-compose exec node /bin/bash -c ' \
        cd /workdir; \
        npm install; \
        npm run build'

bar: 
    docker-compose exec python /bin/bash -c ' \
    cd /workdir; \
    pip install sphinx; \
    make html'
```

Is this correct to use docker compose like this? And what should I change to make it work?

Comment: Maybe it is better to use multi stage docker builds for this requirement: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker compose` not only support container run, but also image build, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build).

So, for your scenario, you should add your package build in `Dockerfile` and exeucte it with `docker-compose up -d --build` which will first build out a docker image then start the service base on the new docker image.

A simple fake code is as next, note next is just to explain the main idea, not a fully workable example, you need to add your stuff base on your real situation.

**Dockerfile.node:**

```
FROM node:12.8.0-buster

# Add related to build
ADD . /srv

# Add all package install
RUN cd /workdir && npm install && npm run build

# Others
......
```

**Dockerfile.python:**

```
FROM python:3.7.4-buster

# Add related to build
ADD . /srv

# Add all package install
RUN cd /workdir && pip install sphinx && make html

# Others
......
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.node
    volumes:
    - .:/srv
  python:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.python
    volumes:
    - .:/src
```

Comment: Thanks. Here you started a service. What if I don't want to start a service but have something similar to `docker run -it image command` ?

Comment: `Service` is just a concept of `docker-compose`, for above, it just same with start container. E.g. for node service, it will first build out a image according to `Dockerfile.node` and tag a image name for you. Let's say the tagged image name is `aaa_node_1` for example, then finally the `docker-compose up` will actual do same as `docker run aaa_node_1`. Compose is just a way to let you make `docker run` etc command be logged in a yaml file which could easily be maintained, also could easily to define start order etc.In fact,when we say `start service`, it's nearly same with `start container`.